# Simple ajax call getting exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm having this ajax call:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
            $("#Result").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        $("#Result").html(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
```

Webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Shared Function GetDate() As String
        Return DateTime.Now.ToString()
    End Function
```

When I run this I'm getting error in console as:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Can anyone say what and where am I going wrong? and If I download the sample provided and it works fine which is mentioned here in this [example](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) by Encosia.

Comment: Can you please try to return a static string other than DateTime.Now.toString() and try to see if it works ? because error 500 shows that there's a problem in your server side.. neither in AJAX nor Havascript

Comment: actually the button itself is not firing...

Comment: A 500 error indicates that the server-side functionality is throwing an exception, you need to find what that exception is.  Does the response body from the server contain an error message?  If you load it manually instead of through an AJAX call, what is the response?  If you attach a debugger to the server-side code, is an exception thrown?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the GetDate() function, does it get hit?

Comment: @David-How can I find out that exception ? No error from response.

Comment: @RickS- It dosent get hit..

Comment: @coder: What *is* in the response body?  Anything helpful at all?  On the server-side configuration, can you turn off custom errors and allow the exception to be displayed?  Then the response body should contain some more useful information.  Also try attaching a debugger to the server-side code and setting it to break on thrown exceptions.

Comment: Get yourself a copy of Fiddler and find out exactly what the error is.  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know what happened but this solved my issue by adding :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but I encountered this in some of my works.
Here's for you to test:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Result", function(){
    var data = {};
    $.post("Default.aspx/GetDate", data, function(msg,status){
        $(this).html(msg.d);
        console.log(msg);
    })
})
```

Comment: Now not getting 500 internal server error but the click of result div is not triggered..

Comment: I've updated the answer to bind the click event. Maybe you have a dynamically loaded page? What does the console say?

Comment: By the way, this is actually prone to error as it will bind the click every time the page is loaded, and will end up in multiple binds. Identify your container and replace `$(document)`